# Is exclamation mark(!) included in regex or glob?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, files, regex

In many articles they never included '!' in glob, which is wrong. **So, where does ! truly belong to ?**

I have used ! in glob eg. `ls lis[!ta]*`
does this mean ! is a part of glob?

Comment: Check the edit.

Answer (score 4):

`!` is used in both shell globs and regular expressions. It doesn't "belong" to either.

In the example that you gave:

```
ls lis[!ta]*
```

it is the POSIX way of negating (or complementing) a character class. From `man 7 glob`

> ```
>    Complementation
>
>    An expression "[!...]" matches a single character, namely any character
>    that is not matched by the expression obtained by  removing  the  first
>    '!'  from it.  (Thus, "[!]a-]" matches any single character except ']',
>    'a' and '-'.)
> ```

(some shells also support `^` for complementation, for consistency with regular expression syntax). It is also used in ksh/bash *extended globs* for a similar purpose, ex.

```
!(foo|bar)
```

matches anything except `foo` or `bar`. For this usage, please refer to the shell's manual page - in `man bash` for example:

> ```
>           ?(pattern-list)
>                  Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
>           *(pattern-list)
>                  Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
>           +(pattern-list)
>                  Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
>           @(pattern-list)
>                  Matches one of the given patterns
>           !(pattern-list)
>                  Matches anything except one of the given patterns
> ```

In perl compatible regular expressions (PCRE),  `!` is also used to negate lookarounds, like

```
foo(?!bar)
```

to match `foo` except where it is followed by `bar`. See for example

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: and where is `set +H` to make it all work?

Comment: If we write something like `!(*.png)` (match everything except `png` images) is expanded as `!(png_1 | png_2 | png_x)` or as `!(png_1 png_2 png_x)`?